# How can I export the list of my apps on my iPhone without using iTunes or a computer?

Tags: ios, applications

I wonder how I can export the list of my apps on my iPhone without using iTunes or a computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in solution to export the list of one's applications on one's iPhone without using iTunes or a computer. One needs to use iTunes or a computer.